# How to get a literal dollarsign in an enumerate environment?

Tags: symbols

I want to mention a Perl variable name within a TeX file for PDF-ing (via `pdflatex`). Masking the dollar sign malfunctions with:

```
   log-file:
   ! Missing $ inserted.
   <inserted text> 
                $
   l.7    \item \textit{\$fmt_line_req}
                                    , d.i. eine den User-W\"unschen angepa\s...
   I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
   you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

The MWE:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    
  \begin{document}
  
  %\begin{enumerate}
  %   \item \textit{\$fmt_line_req}, d.i. eine den User-W\"unschen angepa\ss{}te Formatzeile
  %   \item \textit{\$head_line_req}, d.i. die Spaltenk\"opfe wunschgem\"a\ss{}
  %   \item \textit{\$content_req}, d.i. die Tabellenzeilen mit w.o. gew\"unschter Spaltenpositionierung
  %\end{enumerate}
  
  \begin{enumerate}
     \item \textit{[\%spaltenformatierung\%]}, d.i. eine den User-W\"unschen angepa\ss{}te Formatzeile
     \item \textit{[\%spaltenueberschriften\%]}, d.i. die Spaltenk\"opfe wunschgem\"a\ss{}
     \item \textit{[\%content\%]}, d.i. die Tabellenzeilen mit w.o. gew\"unschter Spaltenpositionierung
  \end{enumerate}
  
  \end{document}
```

The masking of `%` is ok! So, is there a solution to get the dollar sign in this environment?

The following output is only possible if dollar sign lines are commented. The `\textit` format is what I want. But I need itemize/enumerate lines with the dollar sign in same manner.

> 1. *[%spaltenformatierung%]*, d.i. eine den User-Wunschen angepate Formatzeile
> 2. *[%spaltenueberschriften%]*, d.i. die Spaltenkopfe wunschgema
> 3. *[%content%]*, d.i. die Tabellenzeilen mit w.o. gewunschter Spaltenpositionierung

Comment: `_` is for math, escape them as well, aka `\_`

Comment: BTW: i'd probably use the url package and its `\path` macro to format `$fmt_line_req` then we do not need to escape

Comment: newbie error not to know that "_" has this meaning, thank you for polite answer. how can I set to solved?

Answer (score 1):

The characters $ & % # _ { and } are special in LaTeX and can be printed by preceeding them with a \ . Here is a version of your MWE that works.

```
% dollarprob.tex SE 517582 dollar sign
  \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}
     \item \textit{\$fmt\_line\_req}, d.i. eine den User-W\"unschen angepa\ss{}te Formatzeile
     \item \textit{\$head\_line\_req}, d.i. die Spaltenk\"opfe wunschgem\"a\ss{}
     \item \textit{\$content\_req}, d.i. die Tabellenzeilen mit w.o. gew\"unschter Spaltenpositionierung
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{enumerate}
     \item \textit{[\%spaltenformatierung\%]}, d.i. eine den User-W\"unschen angepa\ss{}te Formatzeile
     \item \textit{[\%spaltenueberschriften\%]}, d.i. die Spaltenk\"opfe wunschgem\"a\ss{}
     \item \textit{[\%content\%]}, d.i. die Tabellenzeilen mit w.o. gew\"unschter Spaltenpositionierung
  \end{enumerate}

  \end{document}
```

There are three other special characters (^ ~ ) that can be printed using `\verb`.